# Watchguard BOVPN tunnel not connecting

Tags: vpn, firewall, watchguard

I recently added a new subnet of servers in a remote site and tried to add a VPN tunnel to access them.  The VPN connection was previously in use and is working for some of the routes but not all.  I have Watchguard x5500 at both sites.

The Office -> Remote DC looks like:
192.168.40.0/24  <==> 10.0.10.0/24
192.168.40.0/24  <==> 10.0.20.0/24
192.168.40.0/24  <==> 192.168.10/24

The Remote -> Office lookls like:
10.0.10.0/24     <==> 192.168.40.0/24
10.0.20.0/24     <==> 192.168.40.0/24
192.168.10/24    <==> 192.168.40.0/24

The 10.0.x.x/x routes are working correctly.  The new subnet (which works fine locally) does not connect.  I cannot ping or talk to those servers in anyway.

Anyone know a good way to troubleshoot BOVPN tunnels for Watchguard?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out you have to be very careful with VPN IP addresses.  We had an old setting for a VPN to a network that previously used that subnet.  Once that old setting was removed and only the new VPN claimed that range, it connected.